# How to add event to ckeditor element to un-highlight words

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to create a button on toolbar of Ckeditor that I can highlight words. When words are highlighted, there are "x" button next to them so that we can click on them to remove the highlighting effect.

```
<span class="highlight">sample <span class="remove-highlight></span></span>
```

Implementing highlight is OK for me but the close button (x) is a problem.
Does anyone have any idea? 
Thanks a lot

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code showing how you're currently trying to achieve this?

Comment: Did you tried [mark.js](https://markjs.io)?

Comment: I need something like this one http://ckeditor.com/addon/placeholder but it show the remove button next to the placeholder so that I can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't need the second span. if you have the css rule for remove-highlight you can do:

```
$("#X").on('click',function(){
$("span").removeClass("highlight);

$("span").addClass("remove-highlight");

});
```

but you don't have to physically bind the remove-highlight rule to the html.